# Procedural Butterfly Wings

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I'm working on making some Procedural butterfly wings with Geometry Nodes but I can't quite figure it out. At the moment I am using this awful N-Gon geometry, Wireframe and Subdiv modifiers to create a decent look, but I really want to use Geometry Nodes to generate the wings with much better topology for rigging as well as more control over the tapering of the wing Frame.

I'm quite new to Geo Nodes, but I did try a few things like extruding mesh, points to volume, using float curves to taper curves, but nothing got anywhere near where I am aiming for.

I also wouldn't be opposed to Shader nodes, as I tried that first but was unable to get a decent result procedurally.

[image: Ew Ngons]

[image: Wings!]

Comment: What are you aiming for? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Not a criticism, but an honest question.... Why GN? Do you, for example,  intend to make procedural variations of wing-shape?

Comment: @Leander I'm aiming for something I can use to make multiple different sets of wings. For the set I am working on right now I used a Luna Moth as reference.



@ RobinBetts Yes, I'd like to be able to use a procedural workflow so that I can make multiple variations, especially different shapes. I don't know a lot about GN, so if something like this is a bit too complex or would require a mind-bending amount of nodes, let me know.